# Fast identification of prime power factors?

Tags: primes, factoring

For a given integer exponent $e$, I want to identify all factors of an integer $n$ which are of the form $p^{e}$, where $p$ is a prime. So, for $e = 1$, this is equivalent to getting the unique prime factors, for $e = 2$ it's extracting all of the square factors, etc.

Currently, I am doing this by iterating over the powers of primes and doing trial division; that gets cheaper as $e$ gets larger, as there are fewer prime powers small enough to be candidate factors; given that factoring in general can be done more efficiently than just using trial division, is there an obvious way to speed up this restricted case?

Comment: How large is $n$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Arbitrarily large.

Comment: Arbitrarily large numbers take arbitrarily large time to be factored. Drop it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust And numbers under any fixed bound take constant time to be factored. But that's not exactly a helpful observation. Some large times are still shorter than others, or what would be the point of asymptotic complexity analysis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the worst case, this is probably about as hard as [factoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).  As far as we know, factoring squarefree integers is about as hard as factoring integers in general, so for the case $e=1$, this is likely to be about as hard as factoring.  And, of course, it isn't any harder than factoring, since factoring immediately gives you the answer to your problem.

Factoring is hard for large numbers, but if the number isn't too large, then it's feasible to use a standard factoring algorithm to factor the number and then find the $e$th powers.  This will be far faster than doing trial division with powers of primes for small values of $e$.

For sufficiently large values of $e$, trial division by small primes will be faster.  (It's probably best to use trivial division to find small prime factors, then for each small prime factor, test if the corresponding prime power is a divisor.) But better still is to use [ECM factoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) to find all small prime factors of $n$, then for each small prime factor $p$, test if $p^e$ is also a factor.  (You might use trial division to check for very small prime factors first, before running ECM.)  ECM factoring is the state-of-the-art method to find small factors of a large number.

References:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Square-free_factorization) (note these quotes: "every known algorithm for computing a square-free factorization computes also the prime factorization."; "No algorithm is known for computing any of these square-free factors which is faster than computing the complete prime factorization.")
- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2239/14578
- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/871766/14578
- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14667/14578

Comment: So, for large values of $e$, is there a point where trial division should be expected to become more efficient than generic factoring?

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley, yes, absolutely!  See updated answer (specifically the third paragraph).

Comment: Well, I've got some interesting preliminary data now; maybe using a smarter factorization algorithm would close the gap faster, but with e=1 (so, just regular factoring, no gains from skipping smaller factors), trial division is several orders of magnitude faster than Fermat factoring for n<=5,000,000, and is still twice as fast on the largest precise integer representable in 64-bit floating point. I suppose I shall have to use arbitrary-precision big integers to find where the crossover points are!

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t want to do anything more difficult than trial division:

For the exponent 1 this is practically the same as factoring.

For an exponent e >= 2: You can use trial division by primes 2, 3, 5 etc and when you find a prime factor, you check if it is a high enough exponent, and remove the factor from the number.

But when you would check if your number x is divisible by p, and p^(e+1) > x: x might be a prime raised to the power e, so you check if x is an exact e-th power, and if it is you have found a p which can be raised to the power e.

If x is not an e-th power, then the smallest number with a factor p^e but not an e-th power would be the number p^(e+1) > x, so there is no power of e is a factor.

Say we have e=4 and x about 10^15: Once we want to test p > 1000 where p^5 > x, we check whether x is a 4th power like x = a^4 in which case a is the remaining 4th power factor, or there is no fourth power factor.

If we didn’t eliminate smaller prime factors, then we would in the case e=4 have to check until 2p^4 > x, in this case about p = 4800.  And finding smaller prime factors reduces x.

But when you check the prime p after eliminating all smaller prime factors, then the smallest numbers with a factor q^e are q^e itself

Comment: If you find a prime factor, you can *always* remove it from the number, whether it was divisible by `p^e` or not.  This makes the number smaller, speeding up later divisions (especially for extended-precision, but I think to some degree a smaller dividend and quotient is faster even within a single 32 or 64-bit integer on current CPUs, or at least ones from a few years ago).  And since we're only concerned with powers of *primes*, doesn't interact with divisibility by other prime factors.

Comment: Peter: 2nd paragraph from the end.

Comment: Oh, I was reading "*you check if it is a high enough exponent, and remove the factor from the number.*" as an if-then.  Not as "check whether there are enough factors to meet your threshold for recording elsewhere.  And separately remove the factors you do find."